# SELECT WHERE (EXCEL)

Tags: excel

Есть таблица:

```
А1 А2 А3 А4
1     3  текст
2     1  текст
3     2  текст
```

Как по ключам в А1-А3 получить значение А4 в А2? (SET A2 = SELECT A4 WHERE A1 == A3)

Comment: Напишите понятнее, какое именно значение должно быть в А2 для этих данных.

Comment: @Akina Пожалуйста, можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тупо используем функцию ВПР():

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> А у меня на выходе видно только то, что я написал... И при добавлении формулы столбцы C и D красные...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у меня на выходе видно только то, что я написал... И при добавлении формулы столбцы C и D красные...

Comment: Составьте формулу мастером - он не ошибётся.

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!